# Meaning of set as an element of another set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I understand that sets can be elements of another sets, for example: S={1,3,5,{12}} In this case, the elements of S are 1, 3, 5 and {12}. But 12 doesn't belong to S. I get that, but what is the meaning of that? If the set only containing 12 is an element of S, why isn't 12 an element of S? Is there any situation where this makes a difference?

Comment: E.g., how many elements does $\{42,\{42\}\}$ have?

Comment: 2, 42 and {42}. But I don't understand how that is important. I find it redundant that 42 and {42} are in the same set.

Comment: And how many elements does $\{\{42\}\}$ have?

Comment: It has only one, {42}.

Comment: So $A:=\{42,\{42\}\}$ and $B:=\{\{42\}\}$ must be distinct sets - they differ in their number of elements. But the only way for sets to be different is that they disagree on the element-ness of some object. Here, the only difference is that $42\in A$ and $42\notin B$ -- even though $\{42\}\in A$ and $\{42\}\in B$.

Comment: Ok, I see that it is important theoretically. But what is the actual meaning of A (or B)? A set containing 42 and the set that only contains 42? Does it have an interpretation?

Comment: Of course *theoretically*. It is called set *theory* for a reason. And indeed, "set containing 42 and the set that only contains 42" is the best possible interpretation of the pixel blobs $\{42,\{42\}\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets first check what $a \subseteq b$ means in *Zermelo-Frankael set theory* (the standard foundations), shall we?
$$(a \subseteq b) \;\; :\iff \; \forall x \; (x \in a \; \to \; x \in b)$$
Now, we look at $\{12\} \subseteq \mathbf{S}$, does that imply that $12 \in \mathbf{S}$ in the first place? Well, we've to understand that saying $x \subset y$ is not the same as $x \in y$. One implies that every element of $x$ is an element of $y$, and the other implies that $x$ itself is in $y$.
We see that $\{12\} \in \mathbf{S}$ here, and that $1,3,5 \in \mathbf{S}$. We also see that if $a = \{1,3,5, \{12\}\}$ then $a \subseteq \mathbf{S}$. We also see that if $b = \{1,3,5\}$, then $b \subseteq \mathbf{S}$.
Put another way. If $x = \{1,\{1\}\}$, then it is both true that $1 \in x$, and that $\{1\} \subseteq x$, and also, that $\{1\} \in x$. If we say that $x = \{\{1\}\}$, then $\{1\} \subseteq x$ won't be true. Remember that every object in ZF (*Zermelo-Frankael set theory*) is treated as a set, and so $\{1\}$ is not just a set but a set within a set, which means that $1$ here is also treated as a set. Some other set theories have things called *urelements* which basically allow for the conception of objects like "elements" which are not sets but maybe elements of sets themselves.

Comment: I understand all of that. I know the foundations. I just cant understand what the meaning of x is, for example. ¿A set containing 1 and {1}? Feels redundant to me.

Comment: @Gokiul $\{1\}$ is not the same as $1$ though as I've expressed. One is a set within a set, and the other is just simply a set in ZF. Why does it seem redundant? Because if not so, then I don't understand the question here.
In other words, it is saying (roughly) in plain English that: "the set $1$, and the set $\{1\}$ are in $x$". Knowing that $\{1\}$ is not the same as $1$ and that the former is a set within a set, and the latter is just simply a set.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see any importance to that. Why would you ever use a set that contains {1}?

Comment: It would also say that if $\{1\} \subseteq x$ that every element of $\{1\}$ is in $x$, which is true also. Knowing that $1$ is not the same as $\{1\}$.

Comment: @Gokiul It is general construction to allow you to make any set that you want (and avoid contradictions at the same time); it is not for an exact purpose. Also, you can think of applications right away like the Von Neumann construction of the ordinals that is the first minimal application of the axiom of infinity.

Comment: https://www.math.purdue.edu/~price79/OrdinalNumbers.pdf (page 10)

Comment: Ok, that helps. Thanks!

Comment: If you still want to have elements which are not sets necessarily as I've said, people have come up with things like *urelements*. It is certainly not redundant!

Comment: @Gokiul No problem! :)

Comment: You want $\to$ instead of $\leftrightarrow$ in the first display formula, don't you?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Good catch. Conflated it with extension for a second there.

Comment: @Math3147 There are much simpler "applications" everyone is familiar with. For example taking a powerset of a set.

Comment: @Jonathan Oh, I just picked something randomly off the top of my head. As for the powerset, the axiom of the powerset is actually the reason we've the definition for a subset relation; it is easier to use the revamped set-builder notation (from the axiom of restricted comprehension) to define a powerset.
$$\wp(b) ::= \{x \in B ~ | ~ x \subseteq b\}$$
Much simpler than stating the axiom in its full glory. Sorry for the tangent, it's a point I thought would be worth mentioning.

Comment: Thus I see that being somewhat self-referential or iterative to OP, as it refers basically to the same definition. Although, I totally don't mind the example!